# Which are the safe way to send CString through PostMessage from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, thread-safety

What is the safe / best way to send a `CString` through `PostMessage`, from a thread ?
To create `CString` on heap and clean up when the receiver get this `CString` ?

**Solution 1:** In  thread:

```
CString* pError = new CString(_T("Unknown error"));
::PostMessage(...(LPARAM)pError);
```

and in main thread, somewhere in GUI:

```
CString* pError = (CString*)lParam;
GetDocument()->DoSomething(*pError);
delete pError;
```

**Solution 2:**
Or, to keep `CString` object as member variable inside of `CThread` class ?

```
class CPlanThread : public CThread [: public CObject]
{
public:
DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CPlanThread)

...
protected:
CString* m_pMessage;

};
```

and

```
CPlanThread::CPlanThread()
:m_pMessage(NULL)
{
m_pMessage = new CString(_T(""));
}

CPlanThread::~CPlanThread()
{
if(NULL != m_pMessage)
    delete m_pMessage;
}
```

and somewhere in thread:

```
::PostMessage(m_hWndMain, WMU_NOTIFYTHREAD, 0, (LPARAM)m_pMessage);
```

and in main thread, somewhere in GUI:

```
CString* pError = (CString*)lParam;
GetDocument()->DoSomething(*pError);
```

Both of the above solutions are safe ? Kindly thank you for any explanation.

Comment: I am thinking that in the first solution there is possibility that message could not be processed by main thread, and this will lead to crash ...

Comment: solution 1 but capture it in a unique_ptr so you can't forget to delete it.

Comment: And what if I use this solutions on VC6, where I don't have unique_ptr on that compiler ?

Comment: @RichardHodges: I don't think you can post a unique_ptr.

Comment: @flaviu2: Then I suggest upgrading your compiler.  There are adults today who were born after VC6 was released!

Comment: @RichardHodges: A `std::unique_ptr` doesn't buy you anything, because you are transferring ownership. The `PostMessage`-call would immediately have to call `release()` on it, and the sender cannot retain ownership without extra synchronization (e.g. through `SendMessage`). And at that point, why would you suggest a `std::unique_ptr` to a `CString*`, rather than using a `CString` object with automatic storage duration?

Comment: @IInspectable it buys you exception safety from the moment the message arrives to the moment you no longer need the string (we don't know how long that is). However, the issue is moot. he's using vc6, so it's not really c++.

Comment: @RichardHodges: That's flawed logic. You give up ownership the moment you pass the pointer down the `PostMessage` call. The pointer is then owned by the message queue, and later transferred to the message handling code. You have no way of telling, when that happens, so there is no way for you to know, when it's time to give up ownership in your `unique_ptr`. If anything, your proposed *"exception safety"* is a double-delete bug in disguise.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I think I see now, what you're getting at. By *"capture"* you are referring to the receiving code (not the sender). In that case that's true. I believe VC6 has `std::auto_ptr`, which is good enough for this.

Comment: For solution 2: Isn't it much simpler to pass a pointer to a CString object at AfxBeginThread(YourThread,  &myString) instead using new/delete inside?

Comment: @TomTom: That might appear to be simpler, but now you would need to communicate to the thread, how long it is safe to use this pointer to an object it doesn't own. And you'd also need to synchronization access, because you wouldn't want the worker thread to use the object, when it has run halfway through it's destructor. If you are looking for a simple and safe solution, see [this anwers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42086980/1889329).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first option is the safer alternative.<sup>*</sup> The only reason, why this could result in a resource leak is, if the call to `::PostMessage` fails, and you aren't cleaning up in the sender. Note, that this does not lead to a crash.

The second alternative creates a race condition, since you are holding on to a pointer, whose ownership you meant to transfer. If the GUI thread tries access the string after the thread objects has been destroyed, you are accessing random memory. This can lead to an immediate crash, if you are lucky.

Depending on your specific use case, you might want to consider using a third alternative: Using a `CString` object with automatic storage duration and thread synchronization through message-sending, e.g.:

```
CStringW err( L"Unknown error" );
::SendMessage( ..., (LPARAM)&err );
```

The receiving thread can use the string object for as long as it is in its message handler, and the sender will automatically clean up the resource.

---

<sup>*</sup> *That is assuming, that both threads are implemented in the same module. Make sure to read [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx) in case they aren't.*

Comment: Oooh!  Automatic and SendMessage - yes, that's a *very* good option for handling lifetimes.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Sort of, anyway. The `SendMessage`-call has to pass a (non-owning) pointer, and C++ has no way of expressing this (or C, for that matter, as this is really calling in C code). The receiver could still store that pointer for later use, and take a plunge. Either solution necessitates trustworthy developers, one way or another.

Comment: "Note, that this does not lead to a crash." Can you explain me why this will not lead to a crash ? As long I create on heap an object, and I didn't clean it, this will not lead to a crash ?

Comment: "The only reason, why this could result in a resource leak is, if the call to ::PostMessage fails" how can I know whether ::PostMessage failed ?

Comment: @flaviu2: [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) returns zero, if it fails. `SendMessage` can fail as well, but you wouldn't need any cleanup if you go with my proposed alternative to use an object with automatic storage duration. If you allocate an object on the heap, and throw away the pointer to it, that memory is simply wasted, without any way to reclaim it. This doesn't crash. It's only a waste of address space. If this happens frequently, you'll eventually run out of memory, and allocations will start to fail.

Comment: Can I mark as answer two posts ? :) Because I get two excellent alternative ... I ask to moderator to mark as answer any answer from above, both of them are good ! Kindly thank you for all !

Answer (score 2):

I would always prefer to store things in a member variable (which means there is an object responsible for cleaning them up).  However, see an important caveat below.  I would also prefer to hold a CString by value, rather than by pointer.  Storing the pointer just makes another bit of memory you've got to manage.  So:

```
class CPlanThread : public CThread [: public CObject]
{
public:
DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CPlanThread)

...
protected:
CString m_Message;

};
and

CPlanThread::CPlanThread()
:m_Message(L"")
{
}

CPlanThread::~CPlanThread()
{
}
```

and then

```
::PostMessage(m_hWndMain, WMU_NOTIFYTHREAD, 0, (LPARAM)&m_Message);
```

Note that this approach means you don't need to do anything in the destructor, and the constructor can initialize the variable (actually, you should have used initialization on the pointer).

I have removed the `_T()` macro.  It's a really bad idea, unless you actually build versions of the software with both types of character (which doubles your testing effort for no benefit).  Just get used to writing your literals with a leading 'L'.

Final comment, there is no point testing if a pointer is `nullptr` before deleting it - delete does that check anyway.

## Important Caveat

This approach means you need to make sure that the `CPlanThread` object exists until after the message is processed - but you had to do that with the pointer member anyway.

If you can't ensure that lifetime, but you can just use string literals, then post a `const wchar_t*` and you don't have to manage lifetimes.

If you can't ensure the lifetime is long enough, and you can't just use literals, then you will have to use the new/delete approach.

Comment: Constructing a `CString` object from a wide character literal can result in a narrowing conversion. If you don't want that to happen, be explicit in your string type, and use `CStringW`.

Comment: @IInspectable: Good point.  I assumed that CString would always be CStringW in their codebase.

Comment: Right. And then you are told that they are using VC6 ... On a more serious note, you can disable ANSI/Unicode conversions by defining the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` preprocessor symbol (see [CString::CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx#cstringt__cstringt)).

Comment: Yes.  If they are using VC6, CString is probably CStringA.

Comment: "If you can't ensure the lifetime is long enough, and you can't just use literals, then you will have to use the new/delete approach." You mean, first solution, I am right ?

Comment: @flaviu2 : Exactly